# Laravel - Resource get all relation of an array

Tags: laravel

I'm having having trouble getting all the relation of an array inside the resource. I wanted to get all the `departments` related to the `objectives` set by the employee.

```
public function toArray($request)
  {
    $defaultData = !$this->resource !== null ? parent::toArray($request) : '';

    $additionalData = [

      // Position is not an array so it is a successful return
      'position' => $this->employee !== null ? $this->employee->position->departments : '',

       //Property [departments] does not exist on this collection instance.
      'objective_department' => $this->employee !== null ? $this->employee->objectives->departments  

    return array_merge($defaultData, $additionalData);
  }
```

**Relationship**

```
public function departments() 
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Department');    
}

public function objectives() 
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Objective', 'department_id');  
}
```

**EDIT:**

The data I'm currently getting from my `api` is

```
   {
    id: 1
    objectives: [
     {
       id: 1
       department_id: 2
     }
     {
       id: 2
       department_id: 2
     }
   ]
  }
```

I wanted to get all the relationship from `department_id` for each item in the array of `objectives`

Comment: FYI: This statement: `!$this->resource !== null` is a double negative and should be optimized into `$this->resource === null`. Also, you state that you 'are having trouble'. Could you elaborate what you expect, and what actually happens? It helps us help you ;)

Comment: I'll edit up my post for clarification. Thank you sir Rob!